# What happens to the invocation of system call when a process is killed (*nix)?

Tags: linux, unix, process, kernel, system-calls

There is a program which makes a variety of system calls, some of them do IO, some others don't; let's pick a few examples:

- gettimeofday
- fork
- write
- read
- ioctl

What happens in operating system kernel (Linux 2+/FreeBSD7+/OSX) when a process is being killed (SIGKILL) while it is executing a system call? In particular: does every single system call know how to clean-up itself when process termination is imminent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens in operating system kernel (Linux 2+/FreeBSD7+/OSX) when
>   a process is being killed (SIGKILL) while it is executing a system
>   call?

A process executes a system call in the context of kernel mode. At this time if kernel receives any interrupt(signal comes under software interrupt), it would check out for the priority of that particular interrupt. Software interrupt has least priority among all type of interrupt and hence it would continue to execute until it finished the critical path execution. At this point kernel would store its context and would determine the reason and priority of interrupt and service the interrupt(which is in this case is to terminate/kill the program).

However these concepts are bit complicated and may vary on different system. You may want to refer the great book "**The Design Of UNIX Operating System" By Maurice J Bach** which describes these concepts and the implementation in detailed way.

> In particular: does every single system call know how to clean-up
>   itself when process termination is imminent?

Yes, As system calls gets executed in the context of kernel mode on behalf of a process.
So they always do have the logic to clean-up while process has started to abort/terminate. If user mode program terminates due to unexpected reason,kernel ensures that it clean up all the resources of that particular process. This is the great thing about kernel.

Comment: If the kernel is servicing an ioctl for a process and the process gets a SIGSEV or SIGKILL signal. Then will the process only get killed after the kernel finishes the ioclt and returns the value back to the process?